# IntelliJ: Module Libraries Shown as Project Libraries

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, project, libraries

We only have Maven-projects and coming from Eclipse I'm familiar with dependencies being listed within the Eclipse-project of the `pom.xml` they are defined in.

In IntelliJ 2017.2.2 I'd assumed to see something similar, but in the Project view the libraries are listed as "External libraries" on the same level as the modules in the "Project" type. If I switch to "Packages" the libraries become parts of the module, but they are shown as packages, which are a hell lot resulting in being completely pointless.

In the Project Structure dialogue things are becoming clearer, but it's still confusing why the libraries are listed as being project libraries.

Therefore, I want to ask what's with these project libraries? Is that a combined list of libraries appearing in the modules? Or where are they coming from? And why are there any when we clearly don't have any project libraries defined? Did I do something wrong when importing the `pom.xml`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that a combined list of libraries appearing in the modules?

Yes, you are correct, it's exactly the list of all the libraries from all the modules.

There is a plug-in that will show the libraries under modules: [ModuleLibraries](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9618-modulelibraries).

Comment: Thanks, also for the link (it's also possible to install it right from the Settings - Plugins - Browse Repositories). It's not nice to have to install a "hack" on the third day of using a tool... That plugin works on my IntelliJ.